# SSRS: Operator '-' is not defined for types 'Object' on Deploy

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, deployment, ssrs-2012

I have peculiar problem: when I'm trying to deploy  my report, I get the following error:

> Error 1   An unexpected error occurred while compiling expressions.
>   Native compiler return value: ‘[BC30452] Operator '-' is not defined
>   for types 'Object' and
>   'Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportObjectModel.Field'.’.     0   0

However when I build and Run (or preview) the report no error occurs and it works.

My question is:

1. What could cause this?
2. How to trace the error, since it works on Visual Studio environment?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to compare two different types of objects, specifically you are trying to use `-` on a string object or a non-numeric object. Take a look at your expressions, specifically ones which have a minus sign. Your may only be missing some parentheses. For example:

```
=Fields!Total.Value *10 / (Fields!Other_Total) 
--should be-- 
=(Fields!Total.Value *10) / (Fields!Other_Total)
```

> You have attempted to use a unary operator (+, -, or Not) on a type,
>   such as a String, for which it is not defined

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb4637x6.aspx